# how to create new bug in bugzilla using python

Tags: python, bugzilla

how to create new bug in bugzilla using python

Bugzilla version 5.0.2
and Python 2.7

following link says we can create: 
https://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.4/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService/Bug.html#create

but i am looking for sample code

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using python-bugzilla.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-bugzilla/1.2.2

Here is sample code to get a bug.

```
import bugzilla
bz = bugzilla.Bugzilla(url="https://bugzilla.kernel.org")
print bz.getbug(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

after long hunt i got solution ... 
wanted to share

need to install : easy_install bugsy

Here is Python code:

```
    import bugsy
    bugsyObj = bugsy.Bugsy(username="user@abc.com", password="passwd23",   userid=None, cookie=None, api_key=None, bugzilla_url='http://11.110.2.212/bugzilla/rest')
    bug = bugsy.Bug()

    bug.product="PRODUCT_REQUEST"
    bug.component="Work for Windows"
    bug.summary = "THIS IS JUST TEST FROM BUGSY"
    bug.add_comment("THE COMMENT SECTION")
    bug.assigned_to="assignuser@abc.com"
    bugsyObj.put(bug)
    bug.id
```

This will returns the bug id from Bugzilla. It required

Comment: This is giving me - ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Answer (score 0):

A sample example written in python, to create a bug in Bugzilla 5.x, using the rest API .

```
import requests

data = {
    "product" : "TestProduct",
    "component" : "TestComponent",
    "summary" : "This is the best bug report",
    "version" : "unspecified",
    "description" : "This is the best GUI for reporting bugs"
}
url_bz_restapi = 'http://localhost/bugzilla/rest.cgi/bug'
r = requests.post(url_bz_restapi, data=data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os
while True:
    pass
    os.startfile(your file name)
```

- your file name should be the name of you file and after that .py
- if my file is named hi is should be this

`os.startfile(hi.py)`